# Replace the three IF on one

Tags: mysql

CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `Tovar` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idPreparat` MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `drugApt` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `countryApt` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `manfApt` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `md5` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `ix_prep` (`idPreparat`),
    INDEX `ix_md5` (`md5`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

query:

```
 SELECT id,
    IF(COUNT(Tovar.id)=1,Tovar.drugApt,'') AS `drugApt`,
    IF(COUNT(Tovar.id)=1,Tovar.countryApt,'') AS `countryApt`,
    IF(COUNT(Tovar.id)=1,Tovar.manfApt,'') AS `manfApt`
    FROM Tovar
    WHERE Tovar.md5=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
    GROUP BY Tovar.idPreparat
```

how to replace the three IF on one IF(COUNT(Tovar.id)=1,,) ?
add my idea:

```
    CASE COUNT(Tovar.id)>1
WHEN true THEN CONCAT_WS(@drugApt:='Tovar.drugApt',@countryApt='Tovar.countryApt',@manfApt='Tovar.manfApt') 
WHEN false THEN CONCAT_WS(@drugApt:='',@countryApt='',@manfApt='')
END
```

Comment: Give me the table structure, and give me the sample data you want to get

Comment: Replace it with only one `IF`, and still get all three columns `drugApt`,`countryApt`, and `manfApt` in the results?

Comment: @xpy you understood correctly

Comment: I'm afraid that this cannot be done. What is your desired result? get a table with all the ids, and values in  `drugApt`, `countryApt`, and `manfApt` only where id = 1?

Comment: @xpy no, get a table with all data WHERE Tovar.md5=0x00000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: I had the idea to use variables

Comment: You mean `SELECT *
    FROM Tovar
    WHERE Tovar.md5=0x00000000000000000000000000000000` ?

Comment: yes, yes but with the IF test. I added the code below in the topic, I will try to do so

Comment: I don't get it, could you provide a simple explanation of your query and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly, subquery might help with achieving required results:

```
SELECT  tmp.id,
        COALESCE(t.drugApt, '') as drugApt,
        COALESCE(t.countryApt, '') as countryApt,
        COALESCE(t.manfApt, '') as manfApt
FROM    (
            SELECT      id,
                        IF(COUNT(id)=1, 1, 0) as cond
                FROM    Tovar
                WHERE   md5 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
              GROUP BY  idPreparat
        ) tmp
LEFT JOIN   Tovar t
    ON  t.id = tmp.id
    AND tmp.cond = 1
```

Does this help?